# CREATE UNIQUE in Neo4j not working?

Tags: neo4j, unique

I currently have a graph database that tries to model geographical data.

For the sake of simplicity, one of the relationships I'm using is (Object)-[:IS_IN]-(Object) to relate entities (for example place1 is in city1).

Right now I'm trying to add certain places to the DB, while trying to preserve any kind of already existing nodes. So if for example I already have a relationship such as (place1)-[:is_in]->(city1) and then try to add a (place2)-[is_in]->(city1) relationship, it should link place 2 back to the existing city1 node instead of creating a new one with the same name. So I tried using CREATE UNIQUE like this:

MATCH (obj:Object {name: 'place2'}) CREATE UNIQUE (obj)-[:IS_IN]->(city:Object {name: 'city1' })

However, this keeps creating new nodes named city1. What gives? Should I be using MERGE instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MATCH (obj:Object {name: 'place2'}), (city:Object {name: 'city1' } CREATE UNIQUE (obj)-[:IS_IN]->(city)
```

instead.

Comment: Hiya, this is no doubt the right solution, but a but more explanation of why the OPs code is wrong, and why the change you suggest is the right way would go down really well. Don't forget, total newbies are on S/O trying to figure out how al this stuff works and why it breaks :)

Comment: OP, this is the correct answer but as Taryn requested:

The city is being created again because you have it in a CREATE statement. By putting it in a MATCH statement instead, as Stefan did, the node is matched instead of created and only the relationship is created in CREATE UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and found this solution that works fine for me :

```
MERGE (obj:Object {name: 'place2'}) MERGE (city:Object {name: 'city1' }) CREATE UNIQUE (obj)-[:IS_IN]->(city)
```

What this does (as I understand it) : Finds 'place2' node or creates it if it doesn't exist, finds 'city1' node or creates it if it doesn't exist, creates a :IS_IN relationship if it doesn't exist.
So, whatever the initial situation is, you end up with the complete pattern, but no node or relationship dupl.
I tested it with various starting situations and it worked as expected.

Note that I'm a Neo4j and cypher beginner, this may not be the best solution.
The question is old, I answered it anyway because other people may find it useful.